# How Can I hide a div while sidemenu opens

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-5

I made a side-menu with middle content div. On mobile devices, when the side-menu opens, takes whole width but the problem is that while doing that the main content area positions itself under the side-menu div.

I want the main content to disappear when the side-menu opens. I couldn't find a solution. Any help will be appreciated.

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  #menu1,
  #menu2,
  #menu3,
  #menu4,
  #menu5 {
    text-align: center;
    width: 100vw;
    font-size: 16px !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- Side-menu -->
<div class="col-auto">
  <div class="container-fluid" style="padding: 0">
    <div class="row" style="margin-right: 0">
      <div class="d-flex flex-column justify-content-between bg-body-tertiary col-auto min-vh-100" style="padding-right: 0">
        <div class="mt-4">
          <ul class="nav nav-pills flex-column mt-2 mt-sm-0" id="menu">
            <li class="nav-item my-sm-1 my-2">
              <a class="nav-link text-center text-sm-start" href="#menu1" data-bs-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false">
                <i class="fa fa-file-invoice"></i>
                <span class="ms-2 d-none d-sm-inline">Evraklar</span><span class="badge d-none badge-mobil bg-info rounded-pill ms-2">33-1244</span>
              </a>
              <ul class="navbar-collapse collapse ms-1 flex-column" id="menu1" data-bs-parent="#menu">
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a href="#" class="nav-link" aria-current="page" onclick="document.getElementById('main').src='formlar/tab.html'">Gelen Evrak Ekle</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a href="" class="nav-link" aria-current="page">Giden Evrak Ekle</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a href="" class="nav-link" aria-current="page" onclick="document.getElementById('main').src='formlar/gelen-evrak.html'">Gelen Evrak<span class="badge bg-info rounded-pill ms-2">100</span></a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a href="#" class="nav-link" aria-current="page" onclick="document.getElementById('main').src='formlar/taslaklar.html'">Taslaklar<span class="badge bg-info rounded-pill ms-2">100</span></a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a href="" class="nav-link" aria-current="page">Giden Evrak</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a href="" class="nav-link" aria-current="page">Akışlar</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a href="" class="nav-link" aria-current="page">Kayıt Defterleri</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a href="" class="nav-link" aria-current="page">Kep Kutusu</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a href="" class="nav-link" aria-current="page">İmza Listesi<span class="badge bg-info rounded-pill ms-2"></span></a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item my-sm-1 my-2">
              <a class="nav-link text-center text-sm-start" href="#menu2" data-bs-toggle="collapse">
                <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>
                <span class="ms-2 d-none d-sm-inline">Posta</span>
              </a>
              <ul class="navbar-collapse collapse ms-1 flex-column" id="menu2" data-bs-parent="#menu">
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a href="" class="nav-link" aria-current="page">Öge 1</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a href="" class="nav-link" aria-current="page">Öge 2</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item my-sm-1 my-2">
              <a class="nav-link text-center text-sm-start" href="#menu3" data-bs-toggle="collapse">
                <i class="fa-regular fa-envelope"></i>
                <span class="ms-2 d-none d-sm-inline">Mesaj</span><span class="badge d-none badge-mobil bg-info rounded-pill ms-2"><label for="">100</label></span>
              </a>
              <ul class="navbar-collapse collapse ms-1 flex-column" id="menu3" data-bs-parent="#menu">
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a href="" class="nav-link" aria-current="page">Öge 1</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a href="" class="nav-link" aria-current="page">Öge 2</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item my-sm-1 my-2">
              <a class="nav-link text-center text-sm-start" href="#menu4" data-bs-toggle="collapse">
                <i class="fa fa-chart-column"></i>
                <span class="ms-2 d-none d-sm-inline">Raporlar</span>
              </a>
              <ul class="navbar-collapse collapse ms-1 flex-column" id="menu4" data-bs-parent="#menu">
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a href="" class="nav-link" aria-current="page">Öge 1</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a href="" class="nav-link" aria-current="page">Öge 2</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item my-sm-1 my-2">
              <a class="nav-link text-center text-sm-start" href="#menu5" data-bs-toggle="collapse">
                <i class="fa fa-wrench"></i>
                <span class="ms-2 d-none d-sm-inline">Tanımlamalar</span>
              </a>
              <ul class="navbar-collapse collapse ms-1 flex-column" id="menu5" data-bs-parent="#menu">
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a href="" class="nav-link" aria-current="page">Öge 1</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a href="" class="nav-link" aria-current="page">Öge 2</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- main content -->
<div class="col-auto container-fluid d-flex main-content p-0" style="flex-grow: 1">
  <div class="container-fluid d-sm-inline m-0 pb-2">
    <iframe id="main" src="formlar/tab.html" frameborder="0" width="100%" height="95%"></iframe>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include enough (but *only* enough) code to reproduce your issue, your currently-posted code does very little to help us visualise the problem you describe. You really should try to read both the "*[ask]*" and "*[mcve]*" guidelines, to see if your question could be improved.

Comment: No idea what you mean. Which div is the side menu? Which div is the main content? How does the side menu open?

Comment: My bad. the div with iframe is main content and above that is side-menu. sorry for confusion.  when a nav-link(which has id=menu'X') pressed side-menu expands automatically.